# Automatic matrix creator on Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I wanted to create two-dimensional matrixes on an automated routine (depending on inputs) and then make them return to see the results.

Here's my code:

```java
public class Two_dimensional_arrays {

    static int[][] array1;

    public static int[][] create_array(int number1, int number2) {
        int k = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j <= number2; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= number1; i++) {

                array[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }

        return array1;
    }
}
```

The logic behind all of that was to fill any matrix in order like (let's make a 3x3 one)

```
1-2-3

4-5-6

7-8-9
```

So the matrix would be automatically filled (in ascending order), but it didn't work out as expected since I'm kind of new to programming.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually allocate the array somewhere.

```
 static int[][] array1;
```

This declares a variable capable of holding a reference to an array; it is not the array.  The array is allocated by 'new':

```
 static int[][] array1 = new int[3][3];
```

A couple of other points:

1. The 'array' in your loop should probably be 'array1'.
2. Since 'array1' is a member variable there's probably no point in returning it as well.  You could go either way: have a single array, as at present, and your create_array method will overwrite it each time; OR have create_array allocate an array of the intended size (`new int[number1][number2]`) and return it.  I'd go for the latter.
3. The arguments could be named better: 'row_count' rather than 'number1', 'column_count' rather than 'number2' -- or anything similar that conveys the intended meaning. (Typically Java programmers use camel-case names, like rowCount, rather than underscore, but that's not a particularly interesting discussion and not my point here).

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Two_dimensional_arrays {
    
    public static int[][] create_array(int number1, int number2){
        int[][] matrix = new int[number1][number2];
        
        int k = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i<number1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<number2; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }
        
        return matrix;
    }
    
}
```